# Realtime Chat on a web browser

Tags: open-source, real-time, basecamp

Are there any open source applications (or open source code) to implement realtime chat on a webpage like basecamp does?

Answer (score 2):

Openfire is an open source XMPP chat server.  We've used that for years and we love it.

SParkweb is their open source web based chat client: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/sparkweb/index.jsp

Comment: have you used sparkweb and does it work well for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this post in a blog read this:

http://samithafernando.blogspot.com/2012/06/real-time-web-application-development.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Firechat](http://firebase.github.io/firechat/). It's an open source real-time chat project built on [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com).